# Bump2version + pre-commit hook in python code

Tags: python, git, pre-commit, pre-commit.com, bump2version

I'm using bump2version python module to increment my python codebase version automatically. When the pre-commit hook runs after the commit, the version.sh goes into indefinite loop and version keeps on incrementing in **init**.py. Did I miss anything

**.bumpversion.cfg**

```
[bumpversion]
current_version = 0.0.0
commit = True
message = "Merge the new version"
[bumpversion:file:__init__.py]
```

**.pre-commit-config.yaml**

```
repos:
  - repo : local
    hooks:
      - id: VersionIncrement
        name: VersionIncrement
        entry: ./version.sh
        language: script      
        exclude: (.pre-commit-config.yaml)|(.git/)
```

**version.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

git_branch_name=`git branch --show-current`
echo $git_branch_name
if [[ $git_branch_name =~ "feature/" ]]; then
   bump2version --allow-dirty --verbose patch
   exit 0
elif [[ $git_branch_name == "dev" ]]; then
   bump2version --allow-dirty --verbose minor
   exit 0
elif [[ $git_branch_name == "master" ]]; then
   bump2version --allow-dirty --verbose major
   exit 0
else
   echo "branch does not exist"
   exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Well, if `bump2version` commits then you get an infinite loop

Comment: If I make the commit false in the bumpversion.cfg, then the bumpversion not working. It is not incrementing the version

Answer (score 0):

if `bump2version` is making a commit, yes you'll get an infinite commit with your setup

I would **not** recommend automatically bumping a version like you're doing (if you really want to increment some number after every commit, consider using `git describe` which does this automatically without having to change your committed code).  both `git` and `pre-commit` are not designed to do what you're doing.

if you really want to continue with what you're doing you can skip the infinite recursion by doing something like:

```bash
SKIP=VersionIncrement bump2version ...
```

which will utilize [SKIP=](https://pre-commit.com/#temporarily-disabling-hooks) to bypass *itself*

or you can use `bump2version`'s `--dry-run` which may be more appropriate

that said, I really don't expect making a commit to work while you're making a commit -- and will probably break `git` or your history in mysterious ways (especially when coupled with `git commit -a` or such)

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit